# give an active to class to active link

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags

I am writing a python website built on the back of the django framework, I am looking for a way to highlight the current link the user is on depening on what the URL, I thought doing some thing like this would work.

What I have done is create a new application called `nav` and built some templatetags, like so,

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

URL_PATTERNS = {
    'home': (r'^/$',),
}

@register.tag
def nav_selection(parser, token):
    try:
        tag_name, nav_item = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag requires a single argument" % token.contents.split()[0]
    if not (nav_item[0] == nav_item[-1] and nav_item[0] in ('"', "'")):
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag's argument should be in quotes" % tag_name
    return NavSelectionNode(nav_item[1:-1])

class NavSelectionNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nav_item):
        self.nav_item = nav_item
    def render(self, context):
        if not 'request' in context:
          return "" 
        import re
        try:
            regs = URL_PATTERNS[self.nav_item]
        except KeyError:
            return ''
        for reg in regs:
            if re.match(reg, context['request'].get_full_path()):
                return "active"
        return ''
```

In my template I do this

```
<ul id="navigation">{% load nav %}
                <li><a href="{% url views.home %}" class='{% nav_selection "home" %}'>home</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url views.about %}" class='{% nav_selection "about" %}'>about neal &amp; wolf</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url shop.views.home %}" class='{% nav_selection "shop" %}'>our products</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url shop.views.home %}" class='{% nav_selection "shop" %}'>shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url views.look %}" class='{% nav_selection "look" %}'>get the look</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url news.views.index %}" class='{% nav_selection "news" %}'>news</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url contact.views.contact %}" class='{% nav_selection "contact" %}'>contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url store_locator.views.index %}" class='{% nav_selection "finder" %}'>salon finder</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url professional.views.index %}" class='{% nav_selection "contact" %}'>neal &amp; wolf professional</a></li>

            </ul>
```

yet the markup I get out in firebug is this in this example I am browsing the index page

```
<a class="" href="/home/">
```

So something is obviously failing but I cannot see where, can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to check:

Is the `request` object actually in your context? Are you passing it in specifically, or are you using a `RequestContext`?

Why are you defining regexes in your templatetags, rather than using the built-in `reverse` function to look them up in the urlconf?

Do the regexes here actually match the ones in the urlconf?

Have you included your `home` urlconf under the 'home' url somehow?

Comment: Sorry I am really thick when it comes to python, only being doing it about 2 weeks, is this right way to do this? This is not my code, I inherited it, is there a simpler way? how can I view whats in the request object? When I render_to_response my last parameter is RequestContext, is that what you mean? Sorry for being dumb.